# find peaks from complex values vector

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I would like to know  if it is possible to find peaks from data that contains complex values, like the following data:

```
x = [1  2+3i 4  5+6i  0.1+0.2i  10 -1+9i]
```

To find peaks in *real* data, we can easily use the `findpeaks` function in MATLAB. Example:

```
>> data = [2 12 4 6 9 4 3 1 19 7];    
>> pks  = findpeaks(data);

pks =

    12     9    19
```

But I am interested how can I determine what should be criteria to be peaks in complex data? It's modulus? For example if two complex variables are given by

```
x = 3+4i  
y = 2+3i
```

then

```
|x| = sqrt(3*3+4*4) = 5
|y| = sqrt(4+9) = 3.605551275
```

clearly `|y|<|x|`, does it makes any sense? I have tried the following code, but it gives me errors

```
a = [1  2+3i  4+5i  -1  0.1+0.2i];
>> a

a =

  Columns 1 through 3

   1.0000             2.0000 + 3.0000i   4.0000 + 5.0000i

  Columns 4 through 5

  -1.0000             0.1000 + 0.2000i

>> findpeaks(a)
??? Error using findpeaks
Expected X to be real.

??? Error in findpeaks>parse_inputs (line 54)
validateattributes(X,{'numeric'},{'nonempty','real','vector'},...

??? Error in findpeaks (line 43)
[X,Ph,Pd,Th,Np,Str,infIdx] = parse_inputs(X,varargin{:});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to first decide what it means to find peaks in complex data. There's not a clear and unique definition of what a "peak" is in the 2D landscape of the complex plane.

You could define it as a local maximum on the real axis:

```
>> a = [1  2+3i  4+5i  -1  0.1+0.2i];
>> findpeaks(real(a))
ans =
     4
```

or the imaginary axis:

```
>> findpeaks(imag(a))
ans =
     5
```

or the modulus:

```
>> findpeaks(abs(a))
ans =
     6.403124237432849e+00
```

or the angle:

```
>> findpeaks(angle(a))
ans =
     9.827937232473291e-01     3.141592653589793e+00
```

Comment: for peaks i dont need just single vlaue,but vector of peaks,thanks for reply

Comment: let say  for  modulus case?because all others would be similar

Comment: @dato: `a` is just an example you provided; it contains only 1 peak. Other data could give more peaks, of course. Just use `abs()` to find the modulus (which is real, which you know how to find peaks in).